# Is there a better way of returning response from network requests?

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an Authentication class (I am treating this as a model) which accepts login credentials and a closure. The closure returns the network request's response to the controller. I just want to know if this is a better way of doing this, if not what is the best way of doing this?

**Note:** I am using SwiftyJson library

**Model function**

```
func login(userName: String, password: String, completionHandler: (response: JSON) -> ()) {
    let device = UIDevice().identifierForVendor
    let postData = "login=\(userName)&password=\(password)&deviceid=\(device)"

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: APP_SERVICE_LOGIN)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = HTTP_REQUEST_POST
    request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {
            completionHandler(response: JSON(data: data!))
        } else {
            print("Error = \(error)")
            print("Response = \(response)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

**Controller**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    authentication.login("test@test.com", password: "test", completionHandler: {(response: JSON) -> () in
        print(response)
    })
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is correct way of networking.

The only thing I would advise you to have is a separate networking wrapper which takes header, body and completion block and does all the networking on behalf of others.

That way you do no need to deal with `NSMutableURLRequest`, `NSURLSession` etc. time and agains. Call your custom network class with a simple API and you are good. It also helps debugging centred to one place!